# Browse The computer and Upload Images to an external server using CKEdiror

Tags: php, jquery, image, laravel, ckeditor

i am currently working with CKeditor in a larval application , i can add text and modify them and add image URL's also . and i can save the data and now can view the text with the images in my views :) .

Now i want to add a image browse button and upload images to CKEditor from my computer , when i save the form i want to insert those images to an external server and save the text and image paths in database (In one TEXT field) .

i tried with

```
    filebrowserBrowseUrl: '',
    filebrowserUploadUrl: '/uploader/upload.php'
```

What i am currently doing is add the image values to a session variable and only if the form is submitted i can upload the images to the server . also I can set the path in of the images of the editor , so when the form is saved the images in the text area and all the other text will be saved  in a database field .

My question Is this the best way to do it ? I feel this is complex because i can add any number of images to the text area and also the text area can have other texts .

** In my form CKEDitor is not the only field , i have a form loaded inside a jquery modal popup , the CKEditor is also inside that Modal .

Thank you in advance ....

Comment: why dont you take a look at elfinder library for laravel. It is a great file management library with support to integrate with ckeditor.

Answer (score 1):

you can use kcfinder to upload files and images in your application. 
http://kcfinder.sunhater.com/download this is the download link you can also download it from github.. https://github.com/sunhater/kcfinder it is the best and free up loader for ckeditor.. hope it will help you...

Comment: Thank you very much , i will try this :)